# How to Stop AngularJs code for Bootstrap Confirmation Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I am converting old Style window.confirm dialogue boxes to bootsrap Dialogue box.I am calling Javascript function inside angular code which is

```
function showConfirmation(msg)
{
    jQuery('#confirmationModal .modal-body h2').html(msg);
    jQuery('#confirmationModal').modal();       
}
```

Angular Code:

```
{  
 Converting from old style confirmation box
 //if(!window.confirm('Are you sure ')

     var msg= 'Are you sure'; 
    if(ShowConfirmation(msg))
    {

    }
}
```

Now in Angular code I need to get True /false value from confirmation dialog also I need to resume execution based on user input.

Comment: I tend to create a modal service where a scope can be passed from controller to another, and back again. The above code does not seem like the 'angular way' to me.

Comment: @DanielShillcock you create Modal html within Angular code? Do you have sample code ?

Comment: See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal - a very good directive resource

Comment: I did look angular ui or bootbox. But I wanted to create my own

Answer (score 0):

Can you please have a look at below at http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html ?
You can write call back function and apply changes to angular js variables.
Please ensure that you will have to use $scope.apply within your call back function.